# Linking dependencies libraries for arm-linux-gnueabihf

Tags: c, linux, gcc, libraries, ld

I'm working with project for beagle bone board and I'm using `arm-linux-gnueabihf` tools for cross compilation. I downloaded linaro toolchain from its website, extract it then `export` its cross compilation tools like gcc, ld etc. The problem is in linking libraries. For example im using `libusb-1.0` library in that way:

```
-L/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -lusb-1.0
```

it throws errors like:

```
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcurl.so: undefined reference to 'udev_unref@LIBUDEV_183'
```

I solved it by just adding `libudev` - `ludev` but project uses lot of more libraries and adding its all dependencies is tiring.
In the other side when i get cross tools using `sudo apt install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf` and other cross compilation stuff and i use that tool in my project it seems it is resolving all that `undefined references`. Most interesting thing is that arm-linux-gnueabihf tools from apt package is the same linaro cross compilation tools as I downloaded from website. Question is why im getting those undefined references?

Comment: As far as I am concerned, you need to build a rootfs of your target platform, install those libraries within that fs (set it as your root first  using `chroot`). Then you should be able to cross compile.

It is not working right now, because you are trying to use your architecture version of the libraries you need and not arm versions.

Comment: I added armhf architecture to my dpkg so im getting libs for arm-linux-gnueabihf like this `sudo apt install libname:armhf` so answering to you i've got right libs version

Comment: Are you trying to set up an entire system? If it is so, I think this question may be a case of [XY-Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) and I would suggest that you have a look a [buildroot](https://buildroot.org/) or [yocto](https://www.yoctoproject.org/).

Comment: Nope, just building program for that architecture. I can build that on device but it is tedious and takes much more time that why trying to cross compile only a program.

Comment: You could be interested by [pkg-config](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkg-config). See also http://linuxfromscratch.org/

Comment: One remark: you say you are using `arm-linux-gnueabi`, but are referencing `arm-linux-gnueabihf` in the title and the body of your question. You may want to fix the inconsistency.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I just mistyped. This question for sure is about using `arm-linux-gnueabihf`